# Make a Div as Hexagon from one of it's sides

Tags: html, css

How can I make a Div with it's background Image looks like a Hexagon from one side.
Here's an example of what I need exactly : [Demo](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_57806/)

The header in the example/Demo shaped as Hexagon from it's bottom side

Answer (score 1):

You can use some CSS shapes e.g try this:

```css
#hexagon {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 550px;
 background:url(http://tresroyale.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1200x480.gif);
 position: relative;
}
#hexagon:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 500px solid red;
 border-right: 500px solid red;
 border-top: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
 <div id="hexagon"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the div have to contain a background image, just look at the Example

Comment: Please check updated code @BBeta

Answer (score 0):

Give the section below a class of hexagon and add these styles

```
.hexagon::before, .hexagon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 1670px solid #f7f5ed;
    top: -1669px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -10;
}

.hexagon::before {
    border-right: 10000px solid transparent;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.hexagon::after {
    border-left: 10000px solid transparent;
}
```